# How to show $\mathbb{E}[AB\mid B]=B\cdot\mathbb{E}[A\mid B]$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

How to show $\mathbb{E}[AB\mid B]=B\cdot\mathbb{E}[A\mid B]$?

Intuitively, since we are conditioning on $B$, $B$ is already known so we can simply take $B$ out of the expectation operator. But the tricky part is $\mathbb{E}[AB\mid B]$ is a random variable.

Comment: I haven't answered this question but I've up-voted it.  I suggest that the three people who've answered it should do the same. $\qquad$

Comment: Agree with @MichaelHardy. If you answered a question, then it means that  you think the question is useful and should up-vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the following definition as my starting point:

> **Definition.** If $X \in L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \Bbb{P})$ and $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\Bbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}]$ is a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable integrable function for which
>
> $$ \int_{E} X \, d\Bbb{P} = \int_{E} \Bbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}] \, d\Bbb{P} \qquad \forall E \in \mathcal{G} $$
>
> is true.

If $E$ is $\sigma(B)$-measurable, then for all $F \in \sigma(B)$ we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{F} \Bbb{E}[A\mathbf{1}_E \mid B] \, d\Bbb{P}
&= \int_{F} A\mathbf{1}_E \, d\Bbb{P} \qquad & \text{(by definition with $A\mathbf{1}_E$)}\\
&= \int_{F\cap E} A \, d\Bbb{P} \\
&= \int_{F\cap E} \Bbb{E}[A \mid B] \, d\Bbb{P} & \text{(by definition with $A$)} \\
&= \int_{F} \mathbf{1}_E \Bbb{E}[A \mid B] \, d\Bbb{P}
\end{align*}

and hence $\Bbb{P}$-a.s. $\Bbb{E}[A\mathbf{1}_E \mid B] = \mathbf{1}_E \Bbb{E}[A \mid B]$ holds.

Now you may invoke the standard mechanism - the monotone class theorem - to check that the same is true for all $\sigma(B)$-measurable r.v.s $X$ for which $AX \in L^1(\Bbb{P})$.

Alternatively, approximate $B$ by a sequence of simple functions and use the observation above directly together with an appropriate convergence theorem.

(Either cases, you may need to invoke conditional version of MCT or DCT.)

Answer (score 1):

Definition: $$E[AB\mid B]$$ is any random variable $Z$ s.t.

1. $Z$ is $B-$measurable
2. $\forall B_1 \in \sigma(B)$

$$\int_{B_1} Z \, d\mathbb P = \int_{B_1} E[AB\mid B] \, d\mathbb P$$

or

$$E[Z1_{B_1}] = E[E[AB\mid B]1_{B_1}]$$

---

Now we must check if $BE[A\mid B]$ satisfies those.

1. $Z = BE[A|B]$is $B-$measurable

because $B$ is $B$-measurable, $E[A\mid B]$ is $B-$ measurable and the product of $B-$ measurable functions is $B-$ measurable.

2. $\forall B_1 \in \sigma(B)$

$$LHS = E[Z1_{B_1}] = E[BE[A\mid B]1_{B_1}] = E[BE[A1_{B_1}\mid B]] = E[E[BA1_{B_1}\mid B]] = E[BA1_{B_1}]$$

$$RHS = E[E[AB\mid B]1_{B_1}] = E[E[AB1_{B_1} \mid B]] = E[AB1_{B_1}]$$

QED

---

Observe that we used properties of $E[A\mid B]$:

1. $E[A\mid B]$ is $B$-measurable
2. $$E[A\mid B]1_{B_1} = E[A1_{B_1}\mid B]$$

Answer (score 0):

To avoid questions of existence of these expectations, let's assume $A$ and $B$ are bounded a.s.

One definition of conditional expectation: 
$\mathbb E[X\mid B]$ is a measurable function of $B$ such that $\mathbb E[ g(B) \mathbb E[X\mid B]] = \mathbb E[g(B) X]$ for all bounded measurable $g$.
Any two of these are equal a.s.

So let's see: $B \; \mathbb E[A\mid B]$ is a measurable function of $B$, and

$$ \mathbb E[g(B) B \; \mathbb E[A\mid B]] = \mathbb E[g(B) B A] $$